# trying to select a certain category from database

Tags: php, sql

im a real newbie when it comes to sql but im trying to pick up the pieces of my friends site... It all seems to be working fine apart from the left hand navigation to certain categories.
This is the site: http://tyresinwigan.co.uk/new/

The individual manufacturers should point to each manufacturer direct but they seem to be listing the results for all manufacturers.

Here is the code from the **search.php**:

```
                <?php
require_once('const.php');
$link = dbConnect();

$manufacturer_id = 0;
$name = '';
if (isset($_GET['make']) && is_numeric($_GET['make'])) {
$manufacturer_id = (int) $_GET['make'];
}

$query = "SELECT manufacturer_name FROM manufacturer_tbl WHERE manufacturer_id =     $manufacturer_id";
$result = false;
$result = @mysql_query($query, $link);
if (($result) && (@mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)) {
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$name = stripslashes($row['manufacturer_name']);
}

$query = "SELECT *, 
      v.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_alias 
 FROM vehicle_tbl AS v
 LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON v.vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id 
 GROUP BY v.vehicle_id 
 HAVING v.manufacturer_id = $manufacturer_id";

$offers = false;
$offers = @mysql_query($query, $link);
$items = 0;
if ($offers) $items = mysql_num_rows($offers);

function nextOffer() {
global $offers;
global $items;
$items --;
if ($offers && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($offers))) {
    if (! isset($row['image_name'])) { // no image
        $image = 'images/noimagesml.jpg';
    } else {
        $image = 'images/vehicles/sml/'.stripslashes($row['image_name']);
    }
    $title = stripslashes($row['manufacturer_name']).' '.stripslashes($row    ['vehicle_model']);
    $price = number_format((float) $row['vehicle_price_pcm'], 2);
    $id = (int) $row['vehicle_id_alias'];
    echo '<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="contenthead"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="11" height="40" align="left" valign="top"><img src="images/featre_left_hd.gif" width="11" height="23"></td>
                            <td width="100%" align="left" valign="middle" class="contenthead">'.$title.'</td>
                            <td width="11" height="40" align="right" valign="top"><img src="images/featre_rght_hd.gif" width="11" height="23"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="contentpane"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="'.$image.'" width="100"     height="58" class="bordered" alt="'.$title.'"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="princing">from just &pound'.$price.' pcm</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle"><a href="cardeal.php?vehicle='.$id.'"><img src="images/more_butt.gif" width="54" height="20" border="0"></a></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>';
} else {
    echo '&nbsp;';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: besides that it should be `...$res === false...` I can't see where the problem is, please elaborate

Comment: It looks like you posted only the code to list the manufacturers with links...we need to see the code on the other end of the `search.php?make=<?php echo $manufacturer_id; ?>` request.

Comment: Does the problem lie in the search.php rather than the leftnav.php then?

Comment: My apologies! (NEWBIE)

Here is a link to the page code:
http://tyresinwigan.co.uk/new/search.txt

Comment: @Dazwilde please include the search.php code **in this question**. Links tend to get broken over time, which makes this question useless to others over time.

Comment: Hmm, queries seem OK... Can you include the vehicle_tbl structure and a few rows as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_tbl LEFT JOIN image_tbl ON vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id =         image_tbl.vehicle_id  
      WHERE vehicle_tbl.manufacturer_id = $manufacturer_id
      GROUP BY vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id";
```

to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_tbl LEFT JOIN image_tbl ON vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id =         image_tbl.vehicle_id  
      GROUP BY vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id
      HAVING vehicle_tbl.manufacturer_id = $manufacturer_id";
```

Comment: Just one last issue with this page even though its now showing the correct category makes when you click the 'more' button it seems as though its just defaulting to 'cardeal.php?vehicle=0'

Comment: @Dazwilde: change `$id = (int) $row['vehicle_id'];` to `$id = (int) $row['vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id'];`.

Comment: Looks like its still not working after that change.

Ill edit my first question with what code i have now...

Comment: Sorry, then you'll need to specify the fields you need in the query and set an alias for vehicle_id:   `SELECT vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id as v_id, image_name, manufacturer_name, etc....`

Comment: Glad you've got it working.  In the future, it's better if you don't change the broken code in your original question to working code, so that people who find this page in the future will be able to see what *wasn't* working.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong query. The problem isnt in the left menu, but the query on the resulting page. You need to look at that one, and make sure it is formatted properly.

Comment: My apologies! (NEWBIE) Here is a link to the page code: tyresinwigan.co.uk/new/search.txt

Also just noticed another issue this page also pulls the same image for all products!